# Connection refused error in pyaudio and pocketsphinx

Tags: python-2.7, pyaudio, pocketsphinx

hey I have installed pocketsphinx using pip and also pyaudio but I am getting error as when executing script :

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

Comment: You should show the command you were using when you got above error. You should also show how you installed PocketSphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, these are expected messages from pyaudio. Pyaudio tries different sound frameworks one by one and selects the one that works.